# VMWare Workstation 6.5.5 Install Freezes

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, vmware

I am trying to install VMWare Workstation 6.5.5 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit), but at about 2/3 of the progress bar, it freezes where it says:

```
Installing VMWare Player 2.5.5
   Configuring...
```

Interestingly, it is so frozen, that even after I hit cancel, it is still stuck.

CPU consumption is at 0% and the command with which I launched the installer is:

```
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle
```

Anyone has seen this before?

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. A full description of the tricky steps needed to accomplish that can be found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-90/vmware-workstation-6-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-04-install-freezes-854709/#post4218918).

Answer (score 0):

check out this topic : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-90/vmware-workstation-6-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-04-install-freezes-854709/

Comment: ???? @Android Eve has got the same link  , check "here" in last

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.